# Время пребывания на сайте

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

```js
   var startTime = new Date();
   window.onunload = function () {
      var time = new Date() - startTime;
time=Math.round(time/1000);

     
 SendPost(time);    //отправляем на сервер
 }
```

Скрипт считает время от загрузки скрипта до ухода со страницы- работает в Опере, и не работает в Хроме и Фоксе, вероятно из-за onunload . Как поиметь представление о том сколько приблизительно, в среднем, у пользователя открыта страница? (без установки Яндекс Метрика и т.п.)

Comment: Вебсокет, например

Comment: `Как поиметь представление` - вы из Brazzers к нам пришли?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Да(Сценарист-потребитель). Поимей(те) представление, о том почему с Браззерс ассоциируется.