# Отследить время пребывания на сайте

Tags: php, javascript, html, websocket

```js
var startTime = new Date();
window.onunload = function() {
  var time = new Date() - startTime;
  time = Math.round(time / 1000);

  SendPost(time); //отправляем на сервер
}
```

Код который высчитывает время от загрузки скрипта, до закрытия страницы. Работает в Опере, не работает в Хроме и Фоксе(вероятно из-за window.onunload). Как получить данные о времени от загрузки страницы до ее закрытия(отсоединения от интернета, отключения JS, ...), для получения представления о среднем времени пребывания на странице?

Вроде делают с помощью WebSocket. Как это осуществить?

```js
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://echo.websocket.org');
var startTime = new Date();
ws.onclose = function() {
  var time = new Date() - startTime;
  time = Math.round(time / 1000);

  SendPost(time); //отправляем на сервер
}
```

Такой вариант не заработал. Дело в том, что Эхо-сервер сразу же закрывает соединение, или в том, что onclose не срабатывает, если закрыть страницу?

Простой вариант с отсылкой сообщений серверу с идентификатором пользователя и временем от начала сессии, через каждые n секунд реализовать всегда успею...

Comment: Редактируйте вопросы вместо того чтобы создавать дубликаты. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/746532

Comment: В вебсокетах ловите onclose не на клиенте, а на сервере, и сервер пусть сам считает время. Вообще, похоже, вы не пытались сделать вебсокет-сервер, вот найдите информацию про это (я не в курсе как это делать в php) и сделайте